# How to insert variable into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having a little problem, i have a translations JSON variable.
And i want to put it on HTML. Is there a way to make it somehow?

My JS file:

```
var Karting = Karting || {};

Karting = {

lang : 'lv',
translationsLV: {
    "Home" : "Ziņas",
},
}
```

And i want to do this:

My page is static and i'm not using any templating engines.

```
<li><a class="active" href="#">Karting.translationsLV['Home']</a></li>
```

**EDIT:**

Added this:

```
$(window).load( function() {
        var translations;
        if (Karting.lang=='lv')
        {
            translations = Karting.translationsLV;
        }
        else
        {
            translations = Karting.translationsENG;
        }
            }, false );
```

This doesn't show my element

```
document.write(translations['Home'])
```

UncaughtRefferenceError - translations is not defined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write):

```
<li><a class="active" href="#"><script>document.write(Karting.translationsLV['Home'])</script></a></li>
```

Comment: @Cheese try to put this line: ` var translations;` outside the `$(window).load` function , just put it before the function

Comment: @Cheese put relevant code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see what exactly you're doing

Answer (score 3):

Simply use innerHTML for this case.

```
var Karting = {
   lang : 'lv',
   translationsLV: {
      Home: "Ziņas"
   }
},
homeInfo = document.getElementById('homeInfo');
homeInfo.innerHTML = Karting.translationsLV.Home;
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a id="homeInfo" class="active" href="#"></a></li>
```

Comment: this breaks CSS and my elements floats wherewer it wants

Comment: How do this break your css?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON is not correct. There is an extra comma there. It should be

```
{
lang : 'lv',
translationsLV: {
   "Home" : "Ziņas",
}
}
```

Comment: You also have a extra comma as well

Comment: Ok, so having trailing comma's in JSON is **not** incorrect, though it does cause some problems in older browsers. You have removed one trailing comma but you still left one.

Comment: Comma is not for JSON it's for a variable Karting